# JUnits failing in Jenkins

Tags: java, jenkins, junit, build

I am using **Jenkins** to build the project. Maven version used is `3.3.3`, JDK version used is `1.8_51 update`, JUnit version is `4.11`. and cobertura-maven-plugin version used is `2.7`.

All my JUnits are failing when building the multi module maven project in Jenkins with below errors:

**Error1**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: net.sourceforge.cobertura.coveragedata.TouchCollector.registerClass(Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

**Error2**

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class
```

Have anyone faced this issue ? Please help. Many thanks.

**Plugin for cobertura**

```
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cobertura-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                </plugin>
```

Comment: Does the same build work in your local environment? How is your multi-module project configured? Maybe post your pom files?

Comment: Does it work when you run test on your local machine?

Comment: Show your pom, particularly the section with the `cobertura` configuration.

Comment: Carsten and Pawel .. same works in my local environment except test cases which are linux env based.

Comment: @mystarrocks.. I have added the plugin used related to cobertura.